# AXMLS check constraint

Tags: adodb, concrete5

I am creating q site using Conreate 5 CMS.
I am creating a new block and I have to use AXMLS to create a database table. 
I have been able to create a basic table but I would like to extend it to add an check constraint. Below is the code I have written so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema version="0.3">
    <table name="btAddVehicle">
        <field name="bID" type="I">
            <key />
            <unsigned />
        </field>
        <field name="title" type="C" size="100">
            <NOTNULL />
        </field>
        <field name="imgLocation" type="X"></field>
        <field name="year" type="I" size="4"></field>
        <field name="desciption" type="X"></field>

    </table>
</schema>
```

so for the line   I was intending to that size="4" would restrict the number of values to 4. eg 1990,1999 but this didn'st work

I have read this http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-datadict.htm#foreignkey

but it seems unclear
It says 
    `CONSTRAINTS     Additional constraints defined at the end of the field  definition."`

SO would it be something like 
        `<field name="year" type="I" constraint="check([year] LIKE REPLICATE ('[0-9]', 4)) "></field>`

Or do I need to add an at the end of this code

```
`<sql>
    add some kind of alter table to add the constraint 
AlTER tblTable etc....
</sql>`
```

Answer (score 0):

The size=4 only restrict it to a number between 0 and 9999. So no, that won't work.

I don't know how to use CONSTRAINTS either, but I have never needed that. Normally I use Concrete5's [validation helper](https://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/5.6/forms/basic-validation/) to validate values before saving them to the database. This also makes it a lot easier to get it printed out to the user in your view, if needed, using the [validation error helper](https://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/5.6/system/error-handling/)

Hope this helps you...

Comment: If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: From what I understand validating data is quite integral. Relying soley on PHP could be poor for security. 

I think validating using JavaScript, PHP and Database constraints is the best way of ensuring it. However, there is an argument that I am validating 3x which might be wasted. But the way I see it, JavaScript could be turned off and PHP could be attacked so the safest way is to ensure the database's integrity as a minumin.

Comment: I have found this thtorial [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651368/axmls-database-schema-default-values-and-foreign-keys)  and have been trying to follow it for my own example <br/>
I have now tried <br/>

 `<field name="year" type="I">
   <constraint>
    , CHECK (year LIKE '[0-9[0-9][0-9[0-9]')           
     </constraint>
  </field>`<br/>

and I also tried<br/>

`<field name="year" type="I">
   <constraint>
    , CONSTRAINT CHK_ChkYear CHECK ([year] LIKE REPLICATE('[0-9]', 4))           
     </constraint>
  </field>`<br/>

this didn't work either

Comment: Javascript validation is by nature very insecure and should only be used to give a better user experience.

PHP validation I feel is pretty secure, and you could add a [security token](https://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/developers/use-tokens-to-secure-transactions/) to enhance the security if you are getting the data from a form.

Constraints on the database level I would use if data integrity is an issue there has to be considered.

Comment: I found this [Article][1]
  [1]: http://blog.christosoft.de/2012/08/mysql-check-constraint/
It seems mySQL ignores CONSTRAINT statments which makes sense as I created anSQL statement 
`USE Db_Cars;
CREATE TABLE btAddVehicle (
    bID INT(6)UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    title varchar(100) NULL,
    carYear INT(6) NULL, 
  CHECK (carYear LIKE('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'))
 );`

this executed with no errors but when inserting data all values were accepted. 
This leads me to think that @TheNorhman is correct and the only way to validate this is through PHP.